# Reassign Lists after adding new elements to the same Symbol

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I try to Reassign Lists after adding new Elements as the following Examples:

```
m1 = Table[{"A", "B"}, 3]; m2 = Table[{"C", "D"}, 4];
n1 = Range[3]; n2 = Range[4];
```

With

```
AppendTo[ToExpression["m1"],n1]
```

I want to set this to the new List

```
m1={{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

resp.

```
AppendTo[ToExpression["m2"],n2]
```

the new List

```
m2={{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Comment: Experiment with replacing `=` with `:=` and see how you get on.  Then refer to the documentation to learn what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

Presumably in the context of the real application the string containing the variable name is not known in advance like it is in the question.  Otherwise, we could simply reference variables like `m1` and `m2` directly and none of the following complexity would apply.  But under that assumption, use:

```
ToExpression["m1", InputForm, Hold] /. _[s_] :> AppendTo[s, n1]
```

or:

```
ToExpression["m1", InputForm, Function[, AppendTo[#, n1], HoldFirst]]
```

**The Problem, Restated**

The function `AppendTo` has the attribute `HoldFirst` so its first argument is not evaluated.  That is why we get an error message when we try the `AppendTo` expression from the question:

```
AppendTo[ToExpression["m1"], n1]
(* Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[m1] is Protected. *)
```

`AppendTo` is expecting a variable name as its first argument but it is getting the composite expression `ToExpression["m1"].  The first argument is not evaluated "enough".  So, let's try evaluating it:

```
AppendTo[Evaluate@ToExpression["m1"], n1]
(* AppendTo::rvalue: {{A,B},{A,B},{A,B}} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. *)
```

`AppendTo` is *still* not getting a variable name.  Now it is getting the list that is the value of `m1`.  The first argument is now evaluated "too much".  What to do?

**Solutions**

To work around this problem, we need to interpret the variable string as an expression but prevent it from evaluating immediately after this interpretation.  We can use the optional third argument of `ToExpression` to hold the result:

```
ToExpression["m1", InputForm, Hold]
(* Hold[m1] *)
```

Of course, we want to `AppendTo` the symbol, not just `Hold` it.  We can use a pattern replacement:

```
ToExpression["m1", InputForm, Hold] /. _[s_] :> AppendTo[s, n1]
(* {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {1, 2, 3}} *)

m1
(* {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Or, we can replace the third argument of `ToExpression` with a function that applies `AppendTo` directly:

```
ToExpression["m1", InputForm, Function[, AppendTo[#, n1], HoldFirst]]
(* {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {1, 2, 3}} *)

m1
(* {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

We have used the third argument to `Function` to specify that it should not evaluate its first argument since that would constitute "too much" evaluation.

**Security Note**

`ToExpression` will interpret any expression, not just symbols.  So if the string containing the purported symbol name comes from an untrusted source then we ought not blindly use whatever random expression we are given.  It is prudent to at least ensure that the expression is of a type we expect, in this case a symbol:

```
$nasty = "Evaluate@DeleteDirectory[\"realvaluablestuff\", DeleteContents -> True]";
ToExpression[$nasty, InputForm, HoldComplete] /. {_[s_Symbol] :> AppendTo[s, n1], _ -> $Failed}
(* $Failed *)
```

`HoldComplete` is used instead of `Hold` to stymie the clever hacker that put in that `Evaluate`.  The function equivalent would be `Function[, ..., HoldAllComplete]`.

It is out of the scope of this response to try to make even this simple case bulletproof.  But be aware of these issues when untrusted strings are involved.